# How do I resend all emails blocked by a full mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a user who ignored the full mailbox warning and stopped getting emails.

I have found the logs of the emails using the `get-messagetrackinglog`in powershell.

How do I re-queue these emails so they can be resent to the user?

I think this is possible since the logs indicate delivery but are just failing on the store part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails rejected because of mailbox storage quotas are logged and then discarded.

Unless you use [journaling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649(v=exchg.141).aspx) or forward emails for that mailbox you will not be able to "re-deliver" these email